# how to change the pattern of the datetime-local provided in the html input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datetime

Html input of datetime type is

```
Datefield:
<input type="datetime-local" data-date="" data-date-format="DD MMMM YYYY, h:mm:ss">
```

Script contains the below code.

```
$("input").val(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm:ss'));

$("input").on("change", function() {
this.setAttribute(
    "data-date",
    moment(this.value)
    .format( this.getAttribute("data-date-format") )
)
}).trigger("change")
```

I have referred to      `http://jsfiddle.net/g7mvaosL/`
wherein the date pattern can be changed. 
In the similar way, I tried to use type="datetime-local" then it doesn't work.
How to resolve this.

Comment: I want to implement using type="datatime-local" and not type="date".

Answer (score 1):

The date picker returns a year, month, and day.
`console.log(this.value); //returns 2015-08-09`

You're asking it for that and additionally hours, minutes, seconds: something a *date* picker cannot do.

I'm guessing you want to use the current time for the h:mm:ss?  In your code you set it to moment's now.
`$("input").val(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm:ss'));`

But this only occurs once, so you'd need to move this line inside the on change event.

However, there's no bridge that allows you to add two moments together, because it won't make sense.  Adding today + tomorrow would double the current year, month, etc.  Instead you have to use [moment.duration()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/).  Where a moment is defined as single points in time, durations are defined as a length of time.  I wrote a function to help with this by targeting the values we need.

```
function nowAsDuration(){
    return moment.duration({
        hours:   moment().hour(),
        minutes: moment().minute(),
        seconds: moment().second()
    });
}
```

Now you can just use moment.add().

```
var a = moment(this.value);
var b = nowAsDuration();
var c = a.add(b);
```

Updated code. http://jsfiddle.net/w7mj7feh/

Comment: I want to use type="datetime-local" and not date. I want to pass the value to the input from the script using $(input).val . I don't want to specify the value attribute in the input element.

Comment: So just change the type inside the input tag, and give `moment` the correct syntax. Not too hard eh? http://jsfiddle.net/e7fccrjr/

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the info.If i change the pattern to $("input").val(moment().format('DD MM YYYY, hh:mm:ss a') ,then this doesn't work. Any suggestions